# JavaScript: Pass conditional condition as value

Tags: javascript

I have a function that finds elements using jQuery. I then take that element, get a value from it and assign it to a variable. However, sometimes an element will not exist on the document and the function will return `undefined`. This is expected and if the element returned is `undefined` then the variable that gets assigned should also be `undefined`. Since I am using this function to assign variables many times I wanted to make it neat and on one line. I thought using conditionals might be a solution, however, doing this leads to really messy long lines and needing to call the function twice:

```
let html = $(response.body);
let language = getRowElementFromText('Language', html) ? getRowElementFromText('Language', html).find('a').text() : undefined;
let pages = getRowElementFromText('Page', html) ? parseInt(getRowElementFromText('Page', html).text()) : undefined;
```

Is it possible to resolve those issues and somehow pass the condition of the conditional to be used as the value? For example, in this pesudo code `this` would be the value of the conditional:

```
let html = $(response.body);
let language = getRowElementFromText('Language', html) ? this.find('a').text() : undefined;
let pages = getRowElementFromText('Page', html) ? parseInt(this.text()) : undefined;
```

If this not possible is there another more readable way I can accomplish this on one line?

Comment: Just to check, does `getRowElementFromText` return a jQuery wrapper?

Comment: What does `getRowElementFromText` return? It seems to return a jQuery object, but jQuery objects are never falsy, so the truthy part of your conditional operator expression will always be used.

Comment: It returns a jQuery object. My pesudo code should have included: `getRowElementFromText('Language', html).length > 0 ? ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is/will be with the [optional chaining operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) that's new in ES2020 (available via transpilation today). the code would look like this (it only helps so much with the `parseInt` cas):

```
let language = getRowElementFromText('Language', html)?.find('a').text();
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
let pageText = getRowElementFromText('Page', html)?.text();
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
let pages = pageText ? parseInt(pageText) : undefined;
```

`language` would be `undefined` if the element wasn't found.

If you can't use it (because your target environments don't have it yet and you're not transpiling), you could pass in a function that `getRowElementFromText` will call if the element is found:

```
let html = $(response.body);
let language = getRowElementFromText('Language', html, el => el.find('a').text());
let pages = getRowElementFromText('Page', html, el => parseInt(el.text()));
```

`getRowElementFromText` would look like this:

```
function getRowElementFromText(text, html, callback) {
    const result = /*...existing logic...*/;
    return result === undefined ? undefined : callback(result);
}
```

Or perhaps like this (`callback` is optional):

```
function getRowElementFromText(text, html, callback) {
    const result = /*...existing logic...*/;
    return !callback || result === undefined ? result : callback(result);
}
```

---

**Note:** In the above I'm assuming `getRowElementFromText` does actually return `undefined` in some cases ("not found"), and returns a jQuery object in other cases (found). I flag this up because if it *always* returns a jQuery object (which may be empty), jQuery objects are never falsy (not even empty ones).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to jQuery prototype. It receives a fallback string as an argument and when element is not found, returns fallback string:

```js
$.prototype.getText = function(fallback = undefined) {
  return  this.length > 0 ? this.text() : fallback
}

console.log($("#foo").getText())
console.log($("#bar").getText("If the element does not exists, returns given fallback string"))
console.log(`Fallback string default value is: ${$("#baz").getText()}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="foo">If the element exists, return its inner text</label>
```

Usage:

```js
$(selector).getText(fallbackString);
```